# Using workflow to send email but reply-to not working

Tags: 2010, smtp

In SharePoint 2010 Central Administration I have configured outgoing e-mail settings with an SMTP server, from address and reply-to address.

Then I created a list workflow in SPD2010 that uses the Send email action. But when the user receives the email it does not include the reply-to. How can I get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Hope [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/sharepoint2010general/thread/fcf1ca7d-7512-4785-ac7f-682a4bb4b3d6) will be helpful since I resolved the same issue in the past month

Comment: Hi! Can you please add more details to this post (I know it's old, but that makes it even more likely the link will soon break)

Answer (score 0):

you have to configure incoming mail setting in the SharePoint Server.

Check this link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125119/Configuring-Sharepoint-2010-to-Accept-Incoming-Ema

Answer (score 0):

If you use the workflow with System Account it doesn't work. Try with different user.